# Instance where echelon form of a matrix conceals the solution to a system?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, stationary-point

Say I have two equations:

$$y^3+x-y=0$$
$$x^3-x+y=0$$

These are both partial derivatives of some function, and the condition that they're equal to $0$ implies the values of $x,y,z$ are bound are stationary points. I thought I might try and put these values into a matrix to compute the solution to the system. I think I did something wrong here, because it ended up with a case where my matrix *not* being in echelon form actually made it easier to solve.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
        0 & 1 & -1 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

Where it is a matrix of coefficients with each row vector with the form $(y^3,x^3,x,y)$. This matrix here, is actually in reduced echelon form, which tells me that there are two free parameters and that the system can be solved as is by back substitution, but if one does..

$$R2 \to R2 + R1$$

One then has (forming the augmented matrix):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 1 & -1 &| & 0\\
        1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & | & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

And thus it is shown an implication of the system has  been rendered useful to us:

$$x^3 + y^3 = 0$$
$$y^3 +x -y = 0$$

Which is very straightforward to solve as it gives us the insight that $x=-y$. Why, though, did it make sense that doing a row operation *after* my matrix was in $rref$ helped simply the system further? Also, did what I do make sense? Or is the matrix I made not valid? Just tried applying some linear algebra to a calculus exercise. My hunch is that my matrix is invalid because usually our matrix of coefficients belong to $x,y,z$ terms and for mine, $y^3$ is not independent to $y$ like $z$ is to $y$. But, the vector space of all polynomials with degree at most $2$ have $(a,x,x^2)$ terms which seems to contradict my hypothesis.

Comment: You can't solve for the solutions of this system of equations using row reduction because these are not linear equations.

Comment: Applying RRE on a non-linear equation just doesn't make any sense. First of all, the variables $x,x^3$ are not independent. Second of all, the span of solutions to these equations do not form a vector space, so the transformation you are dealing with is non-linear.

Comment: @bat_of_doom Then why does $\mathcal P_2$ form a vector space (the set of all polynomials with degree at most $2$)? Its variables $x,x^2$ are not independent, and the polynomials are non-linear equations.

Comment: @sangstar There, you are not dealing with roots of a particular polynomial, but instead with the functions themselves. If $x^2-2x+1, x^2-3x+2$, are polynomials, any linear combination is a polynomial. But, if $(x-1)(x-2)$ is a polynomial, then, $1+1.2$, which is a linear combination of 1 and 2, is not a root.

Comment: So, in $\mathcal P_2$ the vector space consists of vectors with components of coefficients for the general polynomial of degree at most $2$, and here I'm attempting to form a vector space of roots of polynomials? Where is it given that my vector space is of roots here, and not of a general polynomial like for $\mathcal P_2$?

Comment: @sangstar When you solve a linear equation in variables, x1,x2,...xn, you essentially use the fact that the set of homogenous equations is a vector space. Here, it is not necessary that the sum of 2 solutions be a solution, as pointed out by my earlier comment. If you don't understand the theory, just take it for granted you can't do the same stuff with non-linear equations for solving them.

Comment: @sangstar Please, if you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding both equations we get
$$x^3+y^3=0$$ and this is equal to $$(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)=0$$
can you solve this equation?

Comment: Since &y$ is not constant, no. Good point.

Answer (score 0):

assuming $$x^3, y^3, x, y$$ as variables, the method is valid to reduce the first system to the second (finding the rref is equivalent to manipulate the starting equations)

Comment: Yes, but the given solution will be wrong, because the variables are not independant, and hence no variables are actually 'free'.

Comment: by matrix analysis you find a new set of equation in the 4 variables by linear combination, in this sense the method is valid to symplify the system

Comment: Yes, of course they can be used to simplify the equation. But my point was that you can't use the RRE form directly for a solution, as the variables are not independent. I.e, to say that you can't declare variables free, because of the rank of matrix being less. I think the OP is confused about this. +1 from me if you can clarify this point in your answer, because as the answer stands, it suggests that you can find the solution by RRE.